# How to write down solutions of Yang-Baxter equations for $sl_3$ explicitly?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, integrable-systems

In [the paper](http://www.mscand.dk/article/viewFile/12370/10386), Stolin classifies all quasi-Frobenius subalgebras of $sl_3$. How to write down solutions of Yang-Baxter equations for $sl_3$ explicitly using these quasi-Frobenius subalgebras? Thank you very much.

Comment: This is described in a [previous paper](http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/12369/10385) by Stolin cited in the paper you link to, it is in the same journal just before (pp. 57-80) this one (pp. 81-88).

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, thank you very much.